# copy to last row of another sheet automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy row from one sheet to another based on if column N contains a number larger than 0.9.

The formula works when I replace the first line by sub test() and run the macro from the vbaeditor however I can't get it to work by changes happening in the worksheet Raw Data.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim i As Long
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
Dim Delta As String
Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet

Set wks1 = ActiveSheet
Set wks2 = Worksheets("Charges") 'change to suit
lr1 = wks1.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr1

        lr2 = wks2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wks1.Cells(i, "N").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wks2.Cells(lr2, "A")

Next i
End Sub
```

The above worksheet calcualte will work for what I need execpt I just need it now to not copy previously copied rows.

Comment: Does column **N** contain constants or formulas ??

Comment: effectively just constants but they appear from a dll file linked to the excel file as constants with no excel formula in them. I have worked with them before as constants

Answer (score 1):

This must be inserted in the worksheet code area of the sheet whose column **N** is being updated:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
    Dim Delta As Variant'****************EDIT************
    Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet
    Dim rINT As Range
    Set rINT = Intersect(Target, Range("N:N"))
    If rINT Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set wks1 = ActiveSheet
    Set wks2 = Worksheets("Charges") 'change to suit
    lr1 = wks1.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lr1
        Delta = wks1.Cells(i, "N").Value
        If Delta > 0.9 Then
            lr2 = wks2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wks1.Cells(i, "N").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wks2.Cells(lr2, "A")
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "Macro is Done, Thank you for waiting", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: so both sheets the same? excel stops respongdong and closes down

Comment: @Jonwhite  not sure I understand your question.....the event macro only goes the one of the two sheets.

Comment: oh ok I 'll try it ont he sheet raw data then because thats where the change happens. I get an error on line if delta >0.9

Comment: @Jonwhite error due to delta is `string`, `dim` it as `double` or `single`

Comment: @Jonwhite  make sure there are no **blanks**  in  column **N** ----------->only numeric values

Comment: thnks) @Gary'sStudent

Comment: there is a problem in that each time a new value goes in N it copies all the previous lines aswell. I need each line put there individually

Comment: @Jonwhite  So if you change cell **N30** ,you only want row **#30** copied??

Comment: not quite. I am making a new question soon after 90minutes has passed since this one. Essentially there will be no gaps in data from A1 to N4 if N4 is the last row there. But some rows can disappear and they will shuffle upwards to fill them on the hseet `Charges`. I'm now using worksheet calculate and I can't copy over duplicate rows. I will have all column N as `=m` so that when a row is filled , M will be filled and so will N. The compication wil be when they get shuffled up and I don't want them duplicating copies

Comment: @Jonwhite  Should I delete this Answer??

Comment: I don't know - my new question has been posted now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153179/copy-part-of-a-row-to-another-sheet-unless-already-been-copied-source-rows-can

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to rename the sub to Test and put it in a module. Let's call it Module1. Make sure the sub is not private, so:

```
Sub Test()
  ' your code here
End Sub
```

Then in the VBA Editor, you can go to the Raw Data Worksheet and choose the WorkSheet Change function from the dropdowns and call your Test sub from there. So it would look like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Call Module1.Test
End Sub
```

This will call Sub Test on ANY change within the Raw Data worksheet. This may be more than what you were looking for. If you wanted to just check if a certain column was changed before calling Sub Test, you could add the following code to the Worksheet Change procedure. This tests whether the cell that was changed is in a certain range first before calling the sub. In this case I made the range column N.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim r As Range
  Set r = intersect(Target, Me.Range("N:N"))
  If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Call Module1.Test

End Sub
```

Comment: You are currently copying the EntireRow over to the new sheet. A quick and easy way would be to just delete the contents of Column N by calling wks2.Range("N:N").Clear at the end of Sub Test. Otherwise you will need to change the Copy Paste line to something like: wks1.Range("A" & i & ":M" & i).Copy Destination:=wks2.Range("A" & lr2)

Comment: I really dont know what you mean - I just copied the code from another thread. I need to use worksheet calculate and not copy previously copied rows. - sorry if everyone hates me now

Comment: My comment was in response to your comment on how to only copy columns A:M over. Not copying previous rows is an entirely different question and I would suggest you post a separate question for that. The answer will depend on whether the new data can contain duplicate entries or whether you are only looking to copy the current row that you are changing in Raw Data.

Comment: oh ok I wil give your suggestion a go actually it will help alot - both in creatnig a new question and altering that line. thanks everyone