# copy part of a row to another sheet unless already been copied. Source rows can change row

Tags: vba, excel

I basically need to copy rows from one sheet to another. The rows which I need to copy are on sheet 2 , columns A to N and I need to copy the rows that has the unique value in column N.

Column N will just be `=M1 or =M2` depending on which row has data on it.

Hence I will use a worksheet calculate event to try capture this.

The tricky part is that each time new values exist in say the last row on sheet 2 and then N gets filled form M. I don't want the previously copied rows to be copied. It may also be the case that the entire contents of the rows change places or that one of the rows disappears and the other row will fill its gap on sheet 2. So I need to avoid the calculate event recognizing this from the `=M` line. i.e if it has already been copied but gets recalcuated - -I don't need it to be copied again.

**I guess one way to do this would be toi lookup if the N column value exists in the N column value on sheet 1. Because if that row disappears then it will be on the sheet 1. it will because I have other formulas putting it there.**

My starting point for dong this is the code below and I have this set in the worksheet code of sheet 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim i As Long
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
Dim Delta As String
Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet

Set wks1 = ActiveSheet
Set wks2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'change to suit
lr1 = wks1.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr1

        lr2 = wks2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wks1.Cells(i, "N").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wks2.Cells(lr2, "A")

Next i
End Sub
```

I also have this working which I would need to incorporate into that worksheet calcualte

```
Sub updt()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets(1) 'Edit sheet name
Set sh2 = Sheets(2) 'Edit sheet name
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr)
For Each c In rng
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh2.Range("A:A"), c.Value) = 0 Then
sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)(2) = c.Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method is pretty sure to copy all wanted rows an then call the remove dublicates function which is almost instantanios. You can simply set your unique col as indicator

Comment: hmm didnt think of that. it might work. what is the code for doing that from the sheet 2 worksheet change event although would that extra code I've now put inthe queston work better if it was changed somehow for the entire row or part of the row?

Comment: @Jonwhite The Code would be: `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:Z999").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=14, Header:=xlYes` You should change the range to what you need. This method is much faster at even medium sized tables than to iterate over all row.

Comment: the sheet to where it is going could contain thousands of lines - are you sure this will not slow excel ?

Comment: @jonwhite Just try it. I used it up to 300k rows and it was basically instantaneous. You have no chance to reach integrated Excel functions speed with classical Iteration via VBA.